# For Each - Compile error next without for

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting Next without For error message - what am I missing? errors on the "next aCell"

[image]

Purpose of this code is to determine the From, To in a Gmail email.  Criteria is based on table within the excel workbook.

```
Sub SetsEmailAddress()

Dim aCell As Range
Dim aCell_1 As Long
Dim strFrom As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim MyString As String

For Each aCell In Sheets("Contact_Rev").Range("A2:A5").Cells
If (aCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) = Sheets("Contact_Rev").Range("P2").Cells Then
   If aCell.Offset(1, 2).Value = "From" Then
        strFrom = aCell.Offset(1, 3).Value
    End If
    Select Case aCell.Offset(1, 2).Value
        Case "Val"
            strTo = (aCell.Offset(1, 3).Value)
        Case "Invoice"
            If IsNumeric(aCell.Offset(1, 3).Value) Then
                For aCell_1 = 1 To aCell.Offset(1, 3).Value
                    strTo = ""
                    strTo = strTo & "" & (aCell.Offset(1, 3).Value) & strTo & "'"
                Next aCell_1
            End If
    End Select
    End If
 Next aCell
end sub
```

Tried it with .cells and without  both give the Subscript error.

Comment: Try `For Each aCell In Sheets("Contact_Rev").Range("A2:A5")` (without `Cells` at the end). Also, what do you mean by `For Each aCell_1 In aCell.Offset(1, 3).Value`? There is only one cell. No `For...Each` seems to be necessary here.

Comment: sorry confused by your answer 'without cells"  When I remove the .cells I get Subscript out of range.  I need to create a string of email addresses, so I thought I needed to reset the cell range to loop thru the list but only if the offset in column 3 = Invoices.

Comment: Feel free to rewrite code - I need to determine if the strto should only be 1 value or a string of all emails.

Comment: You need to remove the `.Cells` two times from your code: `For Each aCell In Sheets("Contact_Rev").Range("A2:A5")` and also `If (aCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) = Sheets("Contact_Rev").Range("P2").Value Then`

Comment: I made your suggestions however, still getting the same error msg.

Comment: On an unrelated, but relevant note, it doesn't look like your filter includes the first column!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with some changes:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetsEmailAddress()

Dim aCell As Range
Dim aCell_1 As Long
Dim strFrom As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim MyString As String

Dim bolFound As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet

bolFound = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Contact rev" Then bolFound = True
Next ws
If bolFound = False Then
    MsgBox "Couldn't find the required sheet." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
End If

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Contact rev")
    For Each aCell In .Range("A2:A9")
        If aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = .Range("M2").Value2 Then
            If aCell.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = "From" Then
                strFrom = aCell.Offset(0, 3).Value2
            End If
            Select Case aCell.Offset(0, 2).Value2
                Case "Val"
                    strTo = "'" & aCell.Offset(0, 3).Value2 & "'"
                Case "Invoice"
                    strTo = strTo & ",'" & aCell.Offset(0, 3).Value2 & "'"
            End Select
        End If
    Next aCell
End With

End Sub
```

Changes:

1. I removed the `.Cells` at the end of the first `For...Each` loop as suggested in the comment above.
2. The second `For...Each` doesn't make sense. Hence, I removed it.
3. Now, `strTo` gets concatenated for each find of a "To" email address in the offsetting cell. To separate these email addresses a `,` is added. You can change it to a `;` if this is what you need.
4. The `Offset` were mostly incorrect (based on the sample data provided and have been adjusted).
5. Finally (and most importantly) the `sub` now searches for the sheet `Contact_Rev` before using it. It turned out (in the sample file provided) that there was no sheet by that name. The sheet name was `Contact rev` (without an underscore). Hence, the sheet was not found and the code could not work.

Comment: thank you however, still does not like the last Next acell - still geting Subscript error.

Comment: error on For Each aCell In Sheets("Contact_Rev").Range("A2:A5")
Subscript error

Comment: Added the End If  and end Select still getting error msg.

Comment: Thanks @findwindow. I added the missing `End If`. I guess one should never post un-tested code. :)

Comment: Why are you converting the isnumeric when the value is an hyperlink?

Comment: I wouldn't know what each of these cells contain. As mentioned in the explanations above: I was just guessing to try to make sense of it. But maybe I was overthinking the problem. I adjusted the code once more to concatenate all the possible finds.

Comment: How do I attach a file with data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115768/discussion-between-ralph-and-karen-schaefer).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing and "End if" near the end - try this:

```
Sub SetsEmailAddress()
Dim aCell As Range
Dim aCell_1 As Range
Dim strFrom As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim MyString As String

For Each aCell In Sheets("Contact_Rev").Range("A2:A5").Cells

    If (aCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) = Sheets("Contact_Rev").Range("P2").Cells Then
       If aCell.Offset(1, 2).Value = "From" Then
            strFrom = aCell.Offset(1, 3).Value
        End If
        Select Case aCell.Offset(1, 2).Value
            Case "Val"
                strTo = (aCell.Offset(1, 3).Value)
            Case "Invoice"
                For Each aCell_1 In aCell.Offset(1, 3).Value
                    strTo = ""
                    strTo = strTo & "" & (aCell.Offset(1, 3).Value) & strTo & "'"
                Next aCell_1
        End Select
    End If

Next aCell
End Sub
```